# Cloud Endpoints is REST or RPC style technology?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

In [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/google-cloud-endpoints-for-android/)  for cloud endpoints i read that: "One of the benefits of being able to easily build your own API is that you can design it any way you want. Cloud Endpoints gives you this flexibility—it allows REST- or RPC-style APIs, or a combination of both.". But of what style (RPC or REST) genereted endpoints methods are ? Seems like RPC (cause i call function on a client side and then it runs on a server side) but they are CRUD methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST or RPC style refers to the protocol. Both of them call procedures to be executed on the server. However, REST style often focuses more on CRUD-style and operating over resources, where RPC style is more procedural. Cloud Endpoints lets you define your API once and exposes interfaces in both RESTful and RPC style.